# Selenium - website's security certificate

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, ssl-certificate, selenium-webdriver

tried - get this error `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url`

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

**end edit**

The website that needs to be tested has a self signed certificate. So Internet Explorer (8 in windows 7) shows the below message message and how this should be handle any leads?

`The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority. The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.`

[image]

if override the link by clicking `"Continue to this website (no recommended)"` then it redirect the page and i get this window which says:

`Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? - with YES | NO button` and whether you click yes/no i get error message which says:

`Unable to open the Internet site <site_name> Operation aborted`

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of IE you should first manually install the certificate on your local machine and then use it. AFAIK there is no other way of circumventing this problem.

Comment: where do i get the certificate from? and how to install?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using selenium rc..you can use `-trustAllSSSlCertificates` option while starting the selenium server.

Comment: I am using selenium 2 (webdriver)

Comment: This is not implemented in IE yet.For achieving the same in firefox you can refer this link.http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UntrustedSSLCertificates

Comment: I don't have any issues with FF

Answer (score 0):

Try the below alternate solution, if the above "certificate installation" process is not helpful. In my case, it was not helpful because of some client restricted settings on my machine. So i used below lines in my Webdriver code.

```
driver.get(baseUrl");
driver.findElement(By.name("overridelink")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

//The above line is for clicking "Continue to this website(not recommended)" link.

Comment: I tried the above code but it does not click `(overridelink)`

Comment: Any luck as I am trying to de same with selenium rc but server hangs up at that point. please let me know if you found a workout

Comment: Did you install cybervillainsCA certificate?

Comment: I did try to install that certificate but it hangs up the server. I am using seleniumserver2.33.0 and .net client driver. Using iexploreproxy and also passing trustallsslcertificate parameter in selenium server. PLease guide.

Comment: After installing the certificate, site is opened without any error but server hangs up saying 23:41:50.946 INFO - Modifying registry settings...
23:41:52.014 INFO - Launching Internet Explorer....and then do nothing. Any Idea